# Joint trajectory action rejected: Controller not connected

Tags: ros-industrial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i get the following error when i try to connect MoveIt! to a KUKA Agilus via the kuka_experimental package. I try to first use the simulation environment.

```
[ERROR] [1466076139.148929605]: Joint trajectory action rejected: waiting for (initial) feedback from controller
[ WARN] [1466076139.149173520]: Controller  failed with error code INVALID_GOAL
[ WARN] [1466076139.149246314]: Controller handle  reports status FAILED
```

I suppose the controller is not connected to the joint_trajectory_action topic. However, my controller is running:

```
$ rosrun controller_manager controller_manager list
joint_state_controller - hardware_interface::JointStateInterface ( running )
```

How can i efficiently debug the problem?

EDIT:

I have loaded the hardware_controllers.yaml which isnt a controller_list and i get

```
[ERROR] [1466425266.321644220]: No controller_list specified.
```

Do i have to create a separate controller_list or should hardware_controller.yaml be formatted to be a controller_list?

These are (some of) the topics i see:

```
/joint_states
/joint_trajectory_action/cancel
/joint_trajectory_action/feedback
/joint_trajectory_action/goal
/joint_trajectory_action/result
/joint_trajectory_action/status
...
/position_trajectory_controller/command
/position_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/cancel
/position_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/feedback
/position_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
/position_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result
/position_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/status
```

[image: image description]

```
<launch>
  <!-- The planning and execution components of MoveIt! configured to run -->
  <!-- using the ROS-Industrial interface. -->

  <!-- Non-standard joint names: -->
   <rosparam command="load" file="$(find kuka_rsi_hw_interface)/config/controller_joint_names.yaml"/>

  <!-- the "sim" argument controls whether we connect to a Simulated or Real robot -->
  <!--  - if sim=false, a robot_ip argument is required -->
    <arg name="sim" default="true" />
    <arg name="robot_ip" unless="$(arg sim)" />

    <!-- load the robot_description parameter before launching ROS-I nodes -->
    <include file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" >
      <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
    </include>

    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/config/controllers.yaml"/>

    <!-- remap topics to conform to ROS-I specifications -->
    <remap from="/position_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" to="/joint_trajectory_action" />
    <remap from="/position_trajectory_controller/state" to="/feedback_states" />
    <remap from="/position_trajectory_controller/command" to="/joint_path_command"/>

    <!-- run the robot simulator and action interface nodes -->
    <group if="$(arg sim)">
      <include file="$(find industrial_robot_simulator)/launch/robot_interface_simulator.launch" />
      <include file="$(find kuka_rsi_hw_interface)/test/test_hardware_interface.launch" />
    </group>

    <include file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
      <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
    </include>

    <include file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
      <arg name="config" value="true"/>
    </include>

    <include file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch" />

  </launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237208/joint-trajectory-action-rejected:-controller-not-connected/) by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: I've just created an example MoveIt configuration package for the KR 6 R900 sixx, see the [kr6r900sixx_moveit_rsi_convenience](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/kuka_experimental/tree/kr6r900sixx_moveit_rsi_convenience) in my fork of `ros-industrial/kuka_experimental`.

See also my answer in [MoveIt and ROS-Industrial: No controller_list specified](http://answers.ros.org/question/237894).

---

This is probably a namespacing issue, or you don't load the `joint_trajectory_controller` (the `joint_state_controller` only *reports* joint states, it doesn't actually control any actuators (confusing, I know)).

For the namespace: from your [previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/236294/kuka_experimental-help-with-installation) I gather that you have your `moveit_planning_execution.launch` file configured for the typical ROS-Industrial driver. That is fine, but that assumes that the ActionServer is listening on topics without any additional namespace prefixed. The `ros_control` infrastructure by default runs its `joint_trajectory_controller` under a namespace. Either remove the namespace, or remap the topics in your launch file. See [abb_experimental/abb_irb120_gazebo/launch/irb120_gazebo.launch](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_experimental/blob/91de854692a8166014f8ec8e3b9565299b79c27d/abb_irb120_gazebo/launch/irb120_gazebo.launch#L4-L7) for an example (for ABB and Gazebo, but the idea is the same).

If you are not loading the `joint_trajectory_controller`, you'll want to add that to your `ros_control` configuration yaml that loads the rest of your controllers. For the `kuka_rsi_hw_interface` package, it should already be loaded ([here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/blob/8c5f0dd746f460c372f063394dbda76e8f7d9fba/kuka_rsi_hw_interface/config/hardware_controllers.yaml#L7-L15), see also the `test` sub dir of `kuka_rsi_hw_interface` for an example).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-06-20**:
I started again from scratch.
Instead of creating a controllers.yaml like in the ROS Industrial tutorial, i just load the param file hardware_controllers.yaml. Apparently that is not a controller list and i get: [ERROR] [1466425266.321644220]: No controller_list specified.

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-06-20**:
According to rqt_graph, the kuka_hardware_interface node seems to be connected to the joint_trajectory_action after the remapping, so this problem might be solved, i still have problems with the controller list

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-20**:
The [test/test_hardware_interface.launch](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/blob/0a45bc177c5210e79b3a9deff0ca1cfffc00ddd7/kuka_rsi_hw_interface/test/test_hardware_interface.launch) file should show you how to load things. Make sure to first load your URDF to the parameter server.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-20**:
Btw, I've captured the difficulty users run into when trying to set this up (without any prior experience with `ros_control`) with [ros-industrial/kuka_experimental#27](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues/27).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-20**:
Also: make sure to update your local clone of `kuka_experimental`. I've updated some bits related to the rsi hw interface recently.

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-06-20**:
Do i need to create another controllers.yaml file like described in
http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot
or is the hardware_controllers.yaml file sufficient? If the latter is the case, wouldnt it need a controller_list prefix of some sort?

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-06-20**:
i have included my launch file for MoveIt. Is there an error evident? Maybe it would be helpful for others too to include one in the repository.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-24**:
The main issue is that I meant for the files in the `test/` directory to be a template / inspiration for your own launch file, not necessarily to be re-used directly.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-14**:
I also meet the[same problem](https://answers.ros.org/question/275661/error-when-roslaunch-the-moveit_planning_executionlsunchmoveitsimplecontrollermanager-action-client-not-connected/)  but I cannot solve it. can you give me some suggestions? Thanks!